# zend framework 2 - issue in using same route name in two diffrent modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-router

I am trying to use same  route names for the 2 different modules, is it possible?

Module **User** :

```
 /*Module.config.php*/

 'dashboard' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/dashboard',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Users',
                        'action'     => 'dashboard',
                    ),
                ),
 ),
```

Module **Admin :**

```
/*Module.config.php*/ 

'dashboard' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/dashboard',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                        'action'     => 'dashboard',
                    ),
                ),
  ),
```

Eventhough I am creating 2 different modules for the dashboard, I am loading only any one action.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What are you wanting to happen? You said you're trying to use two different route names, but both of the routes in your example have the same name, so one will overwrite the other.

Comment: sorry tim, it was 'same route names'

Answer (score 6):

I think you **can not have the same name for two different routes**. Yes it's two different modules, but it's the same application.

The reason is that when the [Zend\ModuleManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html) loads the modules, the event `ModuleEvent::EVENT_LOAD_MODULE` will be triggered and then the [listener](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html#module-manager-listeners) `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener` 
will call the function `getConfig()` of each single Module in your application. And then,  all the `Module->getConfig()` will be merged into one internal configuration called `application.config`.

This is to say that when the modules are loaded, you'll have two routes with th same name, and the difference between the modules doesn't affect nothing in the [routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html).

Even if could do that, you'll encounter other problems as when you want to use [Redirect Plugin](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-redirect), for example the `toRoute` method need the route name as parameter :

> **toRoute**(string $route = null, array $params = array(), 
>        array $options = array(), boolean $reuseMatchedParams = false)

This is a problem if you have to call it with the same route name.

A possible solution for your problem is to set one route and add the module to it, as follows :

**/dashboard/admin/the-rest-of-the-url**

**/dashboard/user/the-rest-of-the-url**

You'll have something like this in your route configuration :

```
'dashboard' => array( 
'type'    => 'segment', 
'options' => array( 
    'route'    => '/dashboard[/:module][/:controller][/:action][/:id]', 
    'constraints' => array( 
        'module'       => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', 
        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', 
        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*', 
        'id'         => '[0-9]+', 
    ), 
    'defaults' => array( 
        'controller' => 'Application', 
        'action'     => 'index',
    ), 
), 
'may_terminate' => true, 
'child_routes' => array( 
    'default' => array( 
        'type'    => 'Wildcard', 
        'options' => array( 
        ), 
    ), 
), 
),
```